# Objective-C: setCenterRect crashes at run time on sprite with alpha=0

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, alpha, cgrectmake

I don't know if this is a known bug.
If I try to set the center rectangle dimensions with setCenterRect in a sprite with an alpha = 0, XCode crushes at run time with:
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x0). No other warnings or errors are provided.
If I run the app on my device (disconnected from Xcode), the app also crashes at start.

This is my code:

```
node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite"];
node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
node.position = CGPointMake(35,110);
node.zPosition = 100;
node.alpha = 0.0; // Make sprite invisible
[node setCenterRect:CGRectMake(0,0.35,1,0.4)];
[parentNode addChild:node];
```

The problem disappears if I set the alpha to a very low number:
    node.alpha = 0.01;

Comment: Try `node.hidden = YES`?

Comment: That also work well.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your help. I am not sure why there would be a conflict between setting the alpha value and the centerRect. But using the hidden property bypass the problem. Thanks again.